# Total distance to drive all roads in network (with some driven multiple times)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

We need to drive all the main roads in Iceland. We are wondering how many KM we need to drive. We see that some roads need to be driven twice to be able to reach all roads.

We have ArcMap basic - Spatial analyst - ArcScan - Network analyst

I've tried OD and Route - it fails and I don't know what I'm doing. The internet information is just costing days of trying no luck.

Does anybody know this?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps search on snow plough routing.  My understanding is that it is an application that needs to traverse all roads.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where it is or a name? I dont see it when I google:).

Comment: It's just an idea.